# Blank space on the bottom of my web page

Tags: html, css

There's a lot of blank space at the bottom of my web page.

I used some CSS to set things up how I wanted them to be layed out, and I think somehow I did something that's causing all the extra blank space.

Any ideas what I can do to reduce that blank space at the bottom?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the content to be centered horizontally on the page? Providing some sample CSS code and being more descriptive about what "how I wanted them to be layed out" means would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, and this is resolution dependent, for example when I use a giant Apple Cinema Display 90° rotated.

Comment: Everything is layed out how I want it to be, I'm just trying to get rid of the extra blank space on the bottom - there's a scroll bar on my computer to scroll down the page, where there shouldn't be, because there shouldn't be any content at the bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean this in the nicest way possible: moving elements into place with a massive `top` value like you're doing with `top: -540px;` is rarely a good method to use.

Most of the code behind the page could do with some reworking, but you can quickly fix the issue you're describing; on `.right1`, set:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 50px;
```

Comment: I have a lot to learn :)
Looks like that worked...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: And is there any reason to use anything in Luke Landwalker's code over what I have?

Comment: And sorry to bother you, but once you're looking at the code, is there anything else that stands out that I should be fixing/changing?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Luke raised a good point: what should happen when the screen is really narrow? Should the icons overlap? Concerning further changes: firstly, you should fix the errors [listed here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flevtecmedia.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), particularly the last one. You should move the `<a>` tag to inside the `div`.

Comment: And I fixed that error - I had originally wanted the whole div to be a link, guess this works better.
Some of the other errors don't look like actual problems...
Should I still be trying to fix them?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may as well fix them, because it's very simple. For the `<meta>` tags, simply make stuff lowercase and add a slash to self-close the tag, like this: `<meta name="description" content="bla bla" />`

Comment: I think some of that was generated by Dreamweaver, or I copied from some other site... Either way, I fixed it all, and it looks like it now passes.
Thanks for the help and the patience, I've learned a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `.right1` class is set to `postion:relative` You need to make it absolute. Here is a UPDATED fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/AQq6T/2/

Comment: `margin-left: 700px` is the wrong way to go. See your answer fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/AQq6T/embedded/result/

Comment: @sehe: Go read all my answers and upvote all the ones that mention jsFiddle :D

Comment: Is there any difference between this version and thirtydot's suggestion?

Comment: @thirtydot: LOL it won't be new for me then, would it :)

Comment: @ Thirtydot the twitter... icons will overlap the main logo see http://jsfiddle.net/AQq6T/1/

Comment: @Luke: I see. Fortunately, I don't think anyone has a screen resolution that narrow. Your solution (unfortunately!) does this with any of the wider resolutions: http://i.imgur.com/VLAED.png

Comment: @thirtydot hmm you're right. I chose the solution most suitable for the jsfiddle view =/.

Comment: @thirtydot I've updated the fiddle. I don't know if it's fully working though, I'm not sure how to view jsfiddles in fullscreen

Comment: @Luke: Still doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/AQq6T/2/embedded/result/ :( You can view fullscreen by clicking the arrow on the "Share" button, and looking at the "embedded version" link.

Comment: Just got an account with jsfiddle because of y'all, not really sure how to use it, but we'll figure it out :)